# Cisco Nexus 1000v %IPQOSMGR-4-QOSMGR_WARNING_MSG

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

I have a Nexus 1000v installation running for well over a year now without any problems.

Recently I noticed that I keep getting a warning every few minutes on CLI.

```
2015 Sep  7 15:13:53 n1kv ipqosmgr[3116]: %IPQOSMGR-4-QOSMGR_WARNING_MSG: Session error status from PPF for client: 0xff01022c, node_id: 0x0, status: 0x41170014  0
2015 Sep  7 15:20:33 n1kv ipqosmgr[3116]: %IPQOSMGR-4-QOSMGR_WARNING_MSG: Session error status from PPF for client: 0xff01022c, node_id: 0x0, status: 0x41170014  0
```

Searching for this warning did not yield any results. Only a cisco manual about Nexus 5000 series and it mentions that no action is required.

Even if this nothing to worry about, the question remains!
What does that warning mean and why did it start now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting both VSMs seems to have stopped the warning.

Restarting only one VSM at a time did not resolve the issue. I had to issue a full reload of both VSMs.

Not really sure what happened that caused this though.